# remove index.php codeigniter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I really can't find a way to make my .htaccess work and eliminate the /index.php/ part from my localhost site's **url**: `http://localhost/ci_intro/index.php/home/`

From XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ci_intro/application/config/ **routes.php** :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

from XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ci_intro/application/config/ **config.php** :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci_intro/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

from XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/ **httpd.conf** :

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

 ...

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

mod_rewrite.so is working, I've checked it with a phpinfo()...

from XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ci_intro/ **.htaccess** :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ci_intro/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?
Please I really need help here, thanks!

Comment: None of these [questions/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=removing+index.php+codeigniter) helped you at all?

Comment: how do you "create" links?

Comment: i'm using codeigniter's library, in the "controller" pages with php's functions i assemble the "views" pages. then the url is created by the function's name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

write this in your htaccess 
check this link to enable mod_rewrite function of 
[apache setting](http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/)

Comment: depends on the host configuration

Comment: sorry, i was working on local. Now that i've uploaded everything on a free host .htaccess is working!

Comment: do you know how to add a php object to the url by .htaccess?

Answer (score -1):

My guess is you didn't have "AllowOverride All" set for your DocumentRoot  object in httpd.conf / apache2.conf