# CodeIgniter removing index.php not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm using Ubuntu 13 with the following setup for a local codeigniter site.

```
Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)
5.5.3-1ubuntu2.2 
'CI_VERSION', '2.1.2'
```

And URLs are no longer working without `index.php`. They used to work, but after upgrading from `Ubuntu 12.x` to `13.x` and a few apache updates over the past year, the `localhost` sites no longer work right.

if I go to `localhost/index.php/controllername/` it works but if I go to localhost/controllername/ it does not.

`mod_rewrite` is enabled.

CodeIgniter config has:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; // tried all available options here and
```

Nothing worked

in the `.conf` file for the domain I have this:

```
<Directory />
  Options -Multiviews +FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

and here's the `.htaccess` file commented lines are ones I tried that didn't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
#  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
#  RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
#    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I’ve Googled and read everything I can find and tried everything I could find including several posts here on Stack Overflow, including the ones in the “Questions that may already have your answer.” Still nothing seemed to work. But like I said, this worked in the past, but only after multiple updates to the OS and Apache did I first notice it stop working.

I’ll be moving away from CodeIgniter with future projects, but these projects already existed. Baffled as to what could be the issue.

SOLUTION:

turns out it was not a codeigniter issue at all. It was an apache issue but not with the rewrite rules.
in my apache2.conf I had to alter the  block for /var/www/

Require all granted seems to have done the trick.

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

just for good measure, I made the change here as well:

        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

found on askubuntu
https://askubuntu.com/questions/421233/enabling-htaccess-file-to-rewrite-path-not-working

Comment: did you set your variable in blank? in config file?

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

should be like this $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: read this also http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/155801/

Comment: look into this its a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814773/remove-index-php-codeigniter/20887134#20887134

Comment: as stated, I saw many questions/answers on SO and none helped my situation. The rewrite rules in that question are exactly what I had but weren't working. Turns out it was not an issue with codeigniter at all, but with the apache config. I had to make some changes in apache2.conf under <Directory /var/www>

Answer (score 1):

copy following code to `.htaccess` in your root folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

Options All -Indexes
```

This works fine for me to remove index.php in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t seem like CodeIgniter has a default `.htaccess`, so unclear where that came from. But for debugging purposes, I would recommend you do the following. First, here is your `.htaccess` all cleaned up:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now replace your `index.php` with this. It just dumps the `$_GET` values passed via the `.htaccess` like so:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';
```

Now with that in your `.htaccess` load the index page of the site/app/project in question. The output should be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [/controllername/here/] => 
)
```

Which appears to be correct. But again, you would know better than us.

The purpose of doing this is to assess whether the issue is either in Apache passing proper `$_GET` values to your CodeIgniter setup, which is one issue. Or whether the issue is within your CodeIgniter controller logic itself.

My gut tells me the issue is in the CodeIgniter logic in your codebase since the upgrade from `Ubuntu 12.x` to `Ubuntu 13.x` includes an upgraded version of `PHP` from version `5.3` in `Ubuntu 12.x` to version `5.5` in `Ubuntu 13.x`. I am using lots of code that works in `PHP 5.3` and `PHP 5.4` but breaks at times in `PHP 5.5` since there are major changes in that codebase that will cause code to break if you don’t keep on top of non-depreciated functions & such.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index)(.*)$ index.php?/myvariable=$1 [L]
```

If you know what GET variable the script is expecting for `controllername` in `localhost/controllername`, then in the rule replace `myvariable` with that variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Place the .htaccess file in the project folder like this:

htdocs/your_project/.htaccess

Try this new code for .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /your-project-directory-name/ 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```