# Remove the index.php in routing in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I put my folder as public_html/vote

And this is the default behavior of the server

```
http://mydomain.com/~voteimbo/  <===the public_html folder
http://mydomain.com/~voteimbo/vote/ <==== the vote folder in public_html
```

The problem is , if I try routing in route.php, unless I add the index.php in my url otherwise it show 404 (The server 404, not codeigniter)

```
 e.g. $route["test"] = front_end/index

 http://mydomain.com/~voteimbo/vote/index.php/test <==== work
 http://mydomain.com/~voteimbo/vote/test <==== 404
```

Here is my setting

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mydomain.com/~voteimbo/vote/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "front_end/check_date";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['test'] = "front_end/index";
```

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Thanks for helping

**Update :**

Attempted the approach here:

[CodeIgniter removing index.php not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357271/codeigniter-removing-index-php-not-working?rq=1)

but the output is

```
Array
(
)
```

so I wonder what is the problem? thanks

Comment: Just put a rewrite base on `RewriteBase /vote/`

Comment: Thanks. But it is the same 404 issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, assuming (*as you stated*) that your codeigniter setup is stored in the directory `/vote/`.

You should be able to do something like this in the htaccess file to be able to access it without the `index.php`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /vote/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

[Here is some more reading related to Codeigniter URL's](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:
Go to your file

> app/Config/App.php

Now, alter the variable **public $indexPage**

Current

```
public $ indexPage = "index.php";
```

Delete "**index.php**" and it will look like this:

```
public $ indexPage. = "";
```